# Passing large amount of rows as a User defined Table value Parameter to SP in Sql Azure taking long time

Tags: azure-sql-database, query-performance, table-valued-parameters

We need to pass around 80K rows to a SP in sql Azure. Previously we are able to do so without any glitches. But currently once we call the SP from c#, it's some times taking 10-15 minutes to start execution in DB and many times the SP is not getting Executed.
one thing I have noticed once we make the call from c#, some operation is getting started in DB. And If I try to alter the Sp, the mentioned operation blocks it. The info about the blocking sessionid is not available in sp_who2 or from "sys.dm_exec_requests"
Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score -1):

I am able to fix the issue with Setting the maxLength of the Columns of the datatable which I sent to DB